# Reorder a vector after changing every value in it(index should be same as before) in R

Tags: r

I have two data frames I want order its value after a little change in the current value.
my data frames are like below

```
V1<-data.frame(name = c("APP_RTYD_A", "APP_GHYD_B", "APP_CHAS_D"))
V2<- data.frame(name = c("NewAPP_GHYD_B_1", "NewAPP_CHAS_D_1", "NewAPP_RTYD_A_2"))
```

I want my data frame V2 also should be in order of data frame V1 as the names in V2 derived from V1 names.

```
 Expected ouput:
V2 <- data.frame(name=c("NewAPP_RTYD_A_2", "NewAPP_GHYD_B_1", "NewAPP_CHAS_D_1"))
```

I have tried using `match()` but as values are not exactly same. it is not working. is there anyway I can match substring from V1 and get same index order of V1 for V2.

```
reorder_idx <- match(V1,V2)
reordered <- V2[reorder_idx]
```

Answer (score 2):

Extract only the part which is relevant from `V2` which can be matched with `V1`.

```
sub('New(.*_\\w+_\\w+)_.*', '\\1', V2)
#[1] "APP_GHYD_B" "APP_CHAS_D" "APP_RTYD_A"
```

and then use `match` and `order`.

```
V2[order(match(sub('New(.*_\\w+_\\w+)_.*', '\\1', V2), V1))]
#[1] "NewAPP_RTYD_A_2" "NewAPP_GHYD_B_1" "NewAPP_CHAS_D_1"
```

---

The opposite approach would be to remove additional text and then `match`.

```
V2[order(match(gsub('New|_\\d+$', '', V2), V1))]
```

---

For the updated dataset :

```
library(stringr)
vals <- str_extract(V2$name, str_c(V1$name, collapse = "|"))
V2[order(match(vals, V1$name)), , drop = FALSE]
```

Comment: I think you don't even need `order` if you switch the arguments in `match` : `V2[match(V1, sub('.*(APP_\\w+_\\w+)_.*', '\\1', V2))]`

Comment: That's correct. Provided `V2` and `V1` are always of same length.

Comment: I want to compare whole name from V1 with V2 name as the names in V2 contains whole string of V1 name except "New" and "_1 or _2" and in case if we are not sure name starts with "APP"

Comment: @Hmm I think that is what my answer is doing.Instead of removing "New", "_1" and "_2" I am keeping the part to match. The answer works for the data you have provided. Did you try it on real data? Did you face any issues? You can replace "APP" with `"\\w+"` as well.

Comment: instead of hard coded "APP" in regular expression can we directly keep name from V1 because we are not sure if name having "APP" will it work

Comment: See Updated answer where I removed hardcoded "APP" from the text. Also I added another approach to remove "New" and the number. @Hmm

Comment: I should not stick to "New" or "APP", I am not sure about the values but for sure names in V2 contains the whole name from V1. and also not sure about the length of the names